# AWS Cognito Azure AD integration with unique callback URL per user

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to integrate Azure AD with AWS Cognito for unique callback URL per user ? eg-If user A login with Azure AD, call back URL is http://localhost/myapp?id=A. For user B, call back URL is http://localhost/myapp?id=B.Understood it is able to do for generic URL.
Thanks.